# How do I enable? Full Text Search is installed in SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition but not enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, enterprise, sql-server-2014-localdb

How can I enable `Full Text Search in SQL Server 2014`.

I've been searching the net for the last couple of hours, some posts about SQL Server 2012 said it's in the features during installation but I went there and I had no options to enabled it.
I determined that it is definitely installed but not enabled running the following query:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') AS IsFullTextInstalled,
       DatabaseProperty(DB_NAME(DB_ID()), 'IsFulltextEnabled') AS IsFulltextEnabled
```

Which returned:

```
IsFullTextInstalled=1
IsFullTextEnabled=0
```

Thanks!

Comment: ["The value of this property has no effect. User databases are always enabled for full-text search. This column will be removed in a future release of SQL Server. Do not use this column in new development work, and modify applications that currently use any of these columns as soon as possible."](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You've got the "installed" part for the instance done. I believe "enabling" has to do with establishing full text search for specific databases within the instance, e.g., using T-SQL and AdventureWorks:

```
--create a full-text catalog
USE AdventureWorks;  
GO  
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG AdvWksDocFTCat;  

-- Ensure the table (Document in this example) has a unique, single-column, non-nullable index
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_ukDoc ON Production.Document(DocumentID);  

-- Create a full-text index on the Document table
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Production.Document  
(  
    Document                         --Full-text index column name   
    TYPE COLUMN FileExtension    --Name of column that contains file type information
    Language 2057                 --2057 is the LCID for British English  
)  
KEY INDEX ui_ukDoc ON AdvWksDocFTCat --Unique index  
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO            --Population type;  
GO
```

Please see the Microsoft article for more detail for this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/get-started-with-full-text-search

And the more generalized tutorial at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/create-and-manage-full-text-indexes